# What appear error in connection between Firebase and Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-console

I have this new project in Xcode:

[image]

And when I tried to create an iOS project in Firebase:

[image]

This error appears:

```
)]}'
{"code":7,"errorSpace":"generic","placeholders":{"trackingId":"68369127...5"},"status":403,"message":"backend error"}
```

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: same here but for android.....did you find any solution?

Comment: @Juan Im not sure why this error occurs, but when I changed browser I was able to download the .plist.

Comment: I just did it on my mac and then transfered the file